# Callback when dependency property receives xaml change

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

When I set the value of `IsClosed` during runtime, `OnIsClosedChanged()` is called fine. 
However, the Designer sets the value of the property but does not call the `OnIsClosedChanged()`.

```
public static DependencyProperty IsClosedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsClosed", typeof(bool), typeof(GroupBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

public bool IsClosed {
    get {
        return (bool)this.GetValue(IsClosedProperty);
    }
    set {
        if ((bool)this.GetValue(IsClosedProperty) == value)
            return;

        this.SetValue(IsClosedProperty, value);
        OnIsClosedChanged();
    }
}



private void OnIsClosedChanged() {
    _rowDefContent.Height = new GridLength((IsClosed ? 0 : 1), GridUnitType.Star);
}
```

Obviously `IsClosed` is not modified by the Designer and only `IsClosedProperty` receives the xaml change. 
My question is: How can I run `IsClosed` after the value has been modified in the Designer. Or at least add some logic to the non-runtime changes.

Comment: Did you try to play around with ValidateValueCallback? Use overloaded method of DependencyProperty.Register https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597501(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I've made same mistake some time ago. Dependency property is something what is deep. The property only exposes it for you, but WPF doesn't uses your property (you can delete it). And @AlexK, comment is right (it could be the answer), use callback to get notified when *dependency property* (not to be mistaken with *your property*) is changed by UI (by designer, by user in run-time, etc).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You would have to register a [PropertyChangedCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback.aspx) with property metadata.

The reason is that dependency properties set in XAML or by bindings or some other source do not invoke the CLR wrapper (the setter method). The reason is explained in the [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563(v=vs.110).aspx) article on MSDN:

> For implementation reasons, it is computationally less expensive to
> identify a property as a dependency property and access the property
> system SetValue method to set it, rather than using the property
> wrapper and its setter.
>
> ...
>
> Because the current WPF implementation of the XAML processor behavior
> for property setting bypasses the wrappers entirely, you should not
> put any additional logic into the set definitions of the wrapper for
> your custom dependency property. If you put such logic in the set
> definition, then the logic will not be executed when the property is
> set in XAML rather than in code.

Your code should look like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsClosedProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsClosed", typeof(bool), typeof(GroupBox),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
            (o, e) => ((GroupBox)o).OnIsClosedChanged()));

public bool IsClosed
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsClosedProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsClosedProperty, value); }
}

private void OnIsClosedChanged()
{
    _rowDefContent.Height = new GridLength((IsClosed ? 0 : 1), GridUnitType.Star);
}
```

Comment: Clemens once again! Found the answer myself a couple minutes ago. But the reference is interesting though... Thx :)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself now. ValidateValueCallback comes really close! (as Alex K has pointed out) But it is a static method and I don't get any reference to the instance which has been changed. The key is to use a PropertyChangedCallback in FrameworkPropertyMetadata which is also an argument passed to the Property.Register method. 
See:

```
public static DependencyProperty IsClosedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsClosed", typeof(bool), typeof(GroupBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsClosedChangedPCC)));

        public bool IsClosed {
            get {
                return (bool)this.GetValue(IsClosedProperty);
            }
            set {
                this.SetValue(IsClosedProperty, value);
                OnIsClosedChanged();
            }
        }



        private static void OnIsClosedChangedPCC(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
            GroupBox current = (GroupBox)d;
            current.IsClosed = current.IsClosed;
        }



        private void OnIsClosedChanged() {
            _rowDefContent.Height = new GridLength((IsClosed ? 0 : 1), GridUnitType.Star);
        }
```

That does now re-set the `IsClosedValue` which triggers the `OnIsClosedChanged` to run.
Thank's for your help guys!

Comment: Right. I meant PropertyChangedCallback of course =)

Comment: Final step: remove `OnIsClosedChanged()` from your property setter method. And **do not set the property again** in the PropertyChangedCallback. That doesn't make sense.