# C#/WPF DependencyProperty Setter not getting called XWidth

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have a very very simple class that demonstrates what I am struggling with in a more complex problem.
Class: MyStateControl
Two Dep Props:
State toggles color (works and setter is called)
XWidth intended to pass its value to Width (Setter is not called)

This is not the real problem that XWidth solves but is used to demonstrate issue.

I am linking XWidth to the SelectedItem of a comboBox. Just to test I linked to other objects and the other objects received the SelectedItems Value. But never My StateControl. Anyone know why?

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace TestDepProp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<double> lstWidths = new ObservableCollection<double>() { 25, 50, 75 };
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listBox.DataContext = lstWidths;
            listBox.ItemsSource = lstWidths;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<double> LstWidths
        {
            get { return lstWidths;}

            set{ lstWidths = value; }
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            stateButton.State = !stateButton.State;
        }
    }
    public class MyStateControl : Button
    {
        public MyStateControl() : base() { }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty StateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "State", typeof(Boolean), typeof(MyStateControl), new PropertyMetadata(false));
        public Boolean State
        {
            get { return (Boolean)this.GetValue(StateProperty); }
            set
            {
                this.SetValue(StateProperty, value);
                if (value == true)
                    this.Background = Brushes.Green;
                else
                    this.Background = Brushes.Red;
            }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty XWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          "XWidth", typeof(double), typeof(MyStateControl), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));

        public double XWidth
        {
            get { return (double)this.GetValue(XWidthProperty); }
            set
            {            
                this.SetValue(XWidthProperty, value);
                this.Width = (double)value;                       
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TestDepProp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestDepProp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

        <Button x:Name="button"  Width="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=listBox}" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="326,54,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="button_Click"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="194" Margin="54,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding lstWidths}"/>
        <local:MyStateControl XWidth ="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=listBox}" x:Name="stateButton" Content="MyStateControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="292,156,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="72" Width="130" State="True" />
        <Label x:Name="label" Content="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=listBox}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="187,54,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="52">

        </Label>
        <Label x:Name="label1" Content="{Binding XWidth, ElementName=stateButton}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="188,156,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: The Link you shared only had Cut and paste from other websites Zeroe code examples. It was somewhat helpful. I have coded the resolution I do not see any place to answer my question and I got no help here as it was not really accpeted as a question. Can I post my resolved code so that others may benefit from the work i did and not just be pointed to a cut and paste answer with no code?

Comment: Your question why the CLR wrapper of a dependency property isn't called is clearly answered in that post. If you are looking for a way to get triggered when a dependency property changes, see e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28302378/1136211.