# UWP UserControle Binding

Tags: dependency-injection, data-binding, uwp

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Template1" ItemsSource="{Binding RecentProjects}" >
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <usercontrole:BtnWithBluring BtnContent="{Binding}"/>                            
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I have the ItemControle and the UserControle inside like DataTemplate.

```
    public Project BtnContent // Project is my own class
    {
        get { return (Project)GetValue(BtnContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BtnContentProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for BtnContent.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BtnContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BtnContent", typeof(Project), typeof(BtnWithBluring), null);


    public BtnWithBluring()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
```

I have this in my UserControle.cs, but when I use breakpoint get and set aren't working
and I don't know why. Help me, please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Callback when dependency property recieves xaml change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301783/callback-when-dependency-property-recieves-xaml-change)

Comment: Yes, this is what I need, thanks