# WPF user control binding two way not working but one way work correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls

I have a date picker user control :

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SelectedDate), typeof(DateTime), typeof(DateTimePicker1), new PropertyMetadata(DateTime.Now));

    public DateTime SelectedDate
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(SelectedDateProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SelectedDateProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

when I'm binding **SelectedDate** of my user control it just work in **one way**.

for example this is my Xaml code:

```
<TextBox x:Name="A2" Text="{Binding SelectedDate,ElementName=A1,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Width="Auto"/>

<userControl:DateTimePicker1 x:Name="A1" IconType="None" Caption="تاریخ 1" Width="400" Height="100" Margin="10" />
```

when I change **SelectedDate** in my *user control* text of TextBox(A1) will changed correctly, but when I change text of text box (or another DateTime value) SelectedDate in my user control will not change.

Comment: You should also show us how your control handles changes of its SelectedDate property, e.g. how any elements in its XAML are bound to the property.

Comment: I said I tried another DateTime value to binding but user control will not update. I use breakpoint on SelectedDate set value but doesn't pass value to SelectedDate

Comment: The breakpoint will not be hit because the SelectedDate property setter is not used at all. When the SelectedData property is data-bound, WPF will call SetValue directly. In order to get notified about property changes, you would usually register a PropertyChangedCallback with the property metadata, e.g. as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28302378/1136211

Comment: As Clemens already suggests: the w error is related to the internal implementation of your UserControl. For some reason you failed to read the value of SelectedDate or to display it. But without knowing the related internals we can't help. Maybe when somebody asks you to post more details you should follow his request to help him helping you...

Comment: I use breakpoint for another Property it worked, but SelectedDate not worked

Answer (score 0):

In my test, It will update `TwoWay`.

[image]

My `DateTimePicker1` is this:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="New_folder.DateTimePicker1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="DateTimePickerControl">
    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding ElementName=DateTimePickerControl, Path=SelectedDate}" />
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Of course it works. It's obvious that the error is related to his internal code, which he refuses to show.

Comment: you use DatePicker in your user control, but I try to create my date picker with Label and Textbox. Default DatePicker worked correctly for me but my own DatePicker not worked

Comment: As @BionicCode said, you should add your `DatePicker` code to help be possible.