# WPF Custom Control, how to force property to update in UI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, .net-6.0

I am having troubles understanding why properties in `Control` are not updated.
I Createde a custom DateTimePicker, and it seems to work mostly fine, beside one issue (I can see). I do not have any experience in creating controls, i almost always created them as View Model and View. But decided i should train if i want to progress.

The problem occurs when exception occurs (I do not throw any exception, and do not catch it during binding. I had created a stirng property that is displayed to user when input issue i had thought about occurs. Though despite throwing this information, the value is not goind back to "original" state, before "faulty" update. It stays at incorrect value, in debugging I am assuming it's due to the fact that property isn't actually changed as it's going back to original state.

Basically i want to update value "25" to previous "09".

[How the problem looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcibH.png)

**Control:**

```
 public class DateTimePicker : Control
{ 

    Button clearButton;
    TextBox hourTextBox;
    TextBox minuteTextBox;
    TextBox secondTextBox;
    #region [Change Handlers]
    public DateTime? selectedDate
    {
        get { return SelectedDate; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                if (value.Value.Date != SelectedDate.Value.Date)
                {
                    UpdateSelectedDate(value);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateSelectedDate(null);
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region[Hour]
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedHourProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(SelectedHour), typeof(string), typeof(DateTimePicker), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(string), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public string SelectedHour
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(SelectedHourProperty);
        set => SetValue(SelectedHourProperty, value);
    }
    #endregion
    #region[Minute]
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedMinuteProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(SelectedMinute), typeof(string), typeof(DateTimePicker), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(string), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public string SelectedMinute
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(SelectedMinuteProperty);
        set => SetValue(SelectedMinuteProperty, value);
    }
    #endregion
    #region[Second]
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedSecondProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(SelectedSecond), typeof(string), typeof(DateTimePicker), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(string), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public string SelectedSecond
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(SelectedSecondProperty);
        set => SetValue(SelectedSecondProperty, value);
    }
    #endregion
    #region[Exception Message]
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ExceptionMessageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(ExceptionMessage), typeof(string), typeof(DateTimePicker), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(string), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public string ExceptionMessage
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(ExceptionMessageProperty);
        set => SetValue(ExceptionMessageProperty, value);
    }
    #endregion
    #region[Selected Date]

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(SelectedDate), typeof(DateTime?), typeof(DateTimePicker), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(DateTime?), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, SelectedDatePropertyChangedCallback));



    public DateTime? SelectedDate
    {
        get => (DateTime?)GetValue(SelectedDateProperty);
        set => SetValue(SelectedDateProperty, value);
    }

    private static void SelectedDatePropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var dateTimePicker = (DateTimePicker)dependencyObject;

        dateTimePicker.selectedDate = dateTimePicker.SelectedDate;

        //update times based on date
        dateTimePicker.SelectedHour = dateTimePicker.SelectedDate != null ? dateTimePicker.GetFromValue(dateTimePicker.SelectedDate.Value.Hour) : null;
        dateTimePicker.SelectedMinute = dateTimePicker.SelectedDate != null ? dateTimePicker.GetFromValue(dateTimePicker.SelectedDate.Value.Minute) : null;
        dateTimePicker.SelectedSecond = dateTimePicker.SelectedDate != null ? dateTimePicker.GetFromValue(dateTimePicker.SelectedDate.Value.Second) : null;
    }
    #endregion
    #region[Minimal Date]
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimalDateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(MinimalDate), typeof(DateTime?), typeof(DateTimePicker), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(DateTime?), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
    public DateTime? MinimalDate
    {
        get => (DateTime)GetValue(MinimalDateProperty);
        set => SetValue(MinimalDateProperty, value);
    }
    #endregion
    #region[Maximal Date]
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximalDateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(MaximalDate), typeof(DateTime?), typeof(DateTimePicker), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(DateTime?), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
    public DateTime? MaximalDate
    {
        get => (DateTime)GetValue(MaximalDateProperty);
        set => SetValue(MaximalDateProperty, value);
    }
    #endregion
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        clearButton = Template.FindName("Part_ClearButton", this) as Button;
        hourTextBox = Template.FindName("Part_Hour", this) as TextBox;
        minuteTextBox = Template.FindName("Part_Minute", this) as TextBox;
        secondTextBox = Template.FindName("Part_Second", this) as TextBox;

        //events
        clearButton.Click += ClearSelectedDate;

        hourTextBox.LostFocus += HourTextBox_LostFocus;
        minuteTextBox.LostFocus += MinuteTextBox_LostFocus;
        secondTextBox.LostFocus += SecondTextBox_LostFocus;
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }
    private void SecondTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string Second = secondTextBox.Text;
        //check for error 
        if(!int.TryParse(Second, out _))
        {
            ExceptionMessage = "Only accepts numeric values";
            SelectedSecond = GetFromValue(SelectedDate.Value.Second);
        }
        else if (int.Parse(Second) < 0 || int.Parse(Second) > 59)
        {
            ExceptionMessage = "Value has to be between 0 and 59";
            SelectedSecond = GetFromValue(SelectedDate.Value.Second);
        }
        else
        {
            ExceptionMessage = null;
            SelectedSecond = GetFromValue(int.Parse(Second));
            UpdateSelectedDate(SelectedDate);
        }
    }
    private void MinuteTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string Minute = minuteTextBox.Text;
        //check for error 
        if (!int.TryParse(Minute, out _))
        {
            ExceptionMessage = "Only accepts numeric values";
            SelectedMinute = GetFromValue(SelectedDate.Value.Minute);
        }
        else if (int.Parse(Minute) < 0 || int.Parse(Minute) > 59)
        {
            ExceptionMessage = "Value has to be between 0 and 59";
            SelectedMinute = GetFromValue(SelectedDate.Value.Minute);
        }
        else
        {
            ExceptionMessage = null;
            SelectedMinute = GetFromValue(int.Parse(Minute));
            UpdateSelectedDate(SelectedDate);
        }
       
    }
    private void HourTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string Hour = hourTextBox.Text;

        if (!int.TryParse(Hour, out _))
        {
            ExceptionMessage = "Only accepts numeric values";
            SelectedHour = SelectedDate.Value.Hour.ToString();
        }
        else if (int.Parse(Hour) < 0 || int.Parse(Hour) > 23)
        {
            ExceptionMessage = "Value has to be between 0 and 23";
            SelectedHour = SelectedDate.Value.Hour.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            ExceptionMessage = null;
            SelectedHour = GetFromValue(int.Parse(Hour));
            UpdateSelectedDate(SelectedDate);
        }
    }
    private void ClearSelectedDate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
    private void UpdateSelectedDate(DateTime? date)
    {
        if (date == null)
        {
            SelectedDate = null;
            return;
        }

        SelectedDate = new DateTime(date.Value.Year,
                                    date.Value.Month,
                                    date.Value.Day,
                                    int.Parse(SelectedHour),
                                    int.Parse(SelectedMinute),
                                    int.Parse(SelectedSecond));
    }
    private string GetFromValue(int value)
    {
        string temp = value.ToString();
        for(int i = temp.Length; i < 2; i++)
        {
            temp = string.Concat("0", temp);
        }
        if (temp.Length > 2) temp = temp.Substring(temp.Length - 2, 2);

        return temp;
    }
}
```

**Resource**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Infinity.controls"
                

    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes">
    <Style TargetType="local:DateTimePicker">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:DateTimePicker">
                    <materialDesign:DialogHost>
                        <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
                            <Grid Background="{StaticResource MaterialDesignBackground}"
                                  Width="300">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="12"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Calendar   x:Name="Part_Calendar"
                                            DisplayDate="{TemplateBinding SelectedDate}"
                                            SelectedDate="{Binding selectedDate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                            Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignCalendarPortraitForeground}"
                                            Background="{StaticResource MaterialDesignBackground}"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            Margin="5"
                                            Grid.Row="1">
                                    <TextBox    x:Name="Part_Hour"
                                                Text="{TemplateBinding SelectedHour}"
                                                Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextBox}"
                                                FontSize="20"
                                                Width="53"
                                                Padding="15 15"/>
                                    <TextBox    x:Name="Part_Minute"
                                                Text="{TemplateBinding SelectedMinute}"
                                                Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextBox}"
                                                FontSize="20"
                                                Width="53"
                                                Margin="10 0 0 0"
                                                Padding="15 15"/>
                                    <TextBox    x:Name="Part_Second"
                                                Text="{TemplateBinding SelectedSecond}"
                                                Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextBox}"
                                                FontSize="20"
                                                Width="53"
                                                Margin="10 0 0 0"
                                                Padding="15 15"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock  Text="{TemplateBinding ExceptionMessage}"
                                            Foreground="DarkRed"
                                            FontSize="10"
                                            FontWeight="UltraLight"
                                            Grid.Row="2"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            Margin="10"
                                            Grid.Row="3">
                                    <Button x:Name="Part_ClearButton"
                                            Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"
                                            Content="Clear"/>
                                    <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatDarkBgButton}"
                                            Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand}"
                                            Content="OK"
                                            Margin="40 0 0 0"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock  x:Name="Part_MainDateDisplay"
                                        Text="{Binding SelectedDate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, StringFormat=dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Margin="0 0 10 0"/>
                            <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignToolButton}"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Content="{materialDesign:PackIcon Kind=ClipboardClock}"
                                    Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </materialDesign:DialogHost>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I tried to implement a `PropertyChangedCallback` on `SelectedHour`, `SelectedMinute` & `SelectedSecond` properties, but to no avail. I assume for same reason, as the value didn't change from original state. Anyone could suggest how i could force this change?

Additionaly, this control is held in `DataGrid` although i want to use it outside it later.
It does revert to prevoius state finally, after i'll hit open the `DialogHost` on another line, but i want to refresh during input.

**If anyone has some other substantive suggestions, I will also welcome them :)**

**EDIT**

Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301783/callback-when-dependency-property-recieves-xaml-change/28302378#28302378)
I tired numerous solutions, but it doesn't solve this issue.
I thinkg in above thread the issue was that it was lacking `PropertyChangedCallback`. Mine is not lacking it but it does not refresh values after manual input. It's probably due to the fact that I want to overwrite new manual value, with previously displayed one.

Each time it's goig to `FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged()` i have both `e.IsAValueChange` and `e.IsASubPropertyChange` set to false.
I need to force the change in case of incorrect input to previous state, unfortunately answer from above doesn't answer this query.

```
    //tried both AffectsRender/BindsTwoWayByDefault
    //tried new PropertyChangedCallback() and lambda method (o, e) => ((DateTimePicker)o).SelectedHourPropertyChangedCallback()
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedHourProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(SelectedHour), typeof(string), typeof(DateTimePicker), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(string), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, new PropertyChangedCallback(SelectedHourPropertyChangedCallback)));

    public string SelectedHour
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(SelectedHourProperty);
        set => SetValue(SelectedHourProperty, value);
    }

    private static void SelectedHourPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var dateTimePicker = (DateTimePicker)dependencyObject;
        dateTimePicker.SelectedHour = dateTimePicker.SelectedHour;
    }
```

Comment: See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28302378/1136211

Comment: Im not sure why it didn't fire on second incorrect attempt. In `DependencyProperty SelectedDateProperty` i implemented `new PropertyChangedCallback(SelectedDatePropertyChangedCallback)` worked at first change, didn't on second. Should i move it to `SelectedHour` etc?

Comment: Well actually it seems to work at random after few changes, this control is added to `DataGrid`.

Comment: After few test it updated due to error from original "09" i typed "26", then it was converted to "9". I thought it worked but in fact it only updated because "09" != "9" :(

Comment: You should be using a more appropriate type, e.g. `int`, instead of string.

Comment: I did it as "09" looks better than "9". Unfortunately, even when i change it to `int` it does not refresh as still 9 == 9 and `OnPropertyChanged` will not run.  Although im thinking of implementing some scrollviewer with values 00-23 and 00-59. But i prefer typing :)